# Creating Array Object Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have seen many tutorial which describes that array is object and its object is referenced by the reference variable like this

```
int a[]=new int[5];
```

But the thing which is confusing me is that , as  to create an object we need constructor like when creating a simple object like this

```
box b1=new box();
```

but when creating arrays object we are not calling any constructor instead we are writing like this int[5] so what is this ? and also what is the datatype of array object ?

Comment: The data type of the array object is exactly what you create - `int[]` in this case. And sure, you're not calling a regular constructor - creating an array just does that, and nothing more. All you need to specify is the size, and you specify that in the square brackets. That doesn't mean it's not an object though...

Comment: you gave the datatype i.e `int` and about constructor ,let's just say compiler  take care of that

Comment: Note that you're not calling a constructor when you create an array - you are just allocating some space to store "stuff"; all the elements are initialized to the default value (zero for numeric types, null for reference types). This is a common cause of confusion for beginners (especially if you know a little bit of C++, where it is different).

Comment: Jon Skeet , In which package int[] class is present?

Comment: Andy Turner, Thanks for a specific answer , has cleared some concepts but still little bit confused...

Comment: There's no int[] package. Arrays takes any object reference. You have a int (which is a primitive type) boxed into array. AnyObject[] will be a boxed AnyObject into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JLS 4.3.1 - Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.

For class instantiation, we need constructors. Arrays does not represent a class, thus constructors are not required. Both classes and arrays have different creation styles. Refer [JLS 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) and [JLS 15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)

Regarding type of arrays, from [JLS 10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array type is written as the name of an element type followed by
>   some number of empty pairs of square brackets []. The number of
>   bracket pairs indicates the depth of array nesting.

Only few classes/interfaces are capable of holding arrays, Refer [JLS 4.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3).

**Edit:**
So, `int[]` or any other array are called reference type, but not class. Objects are referenced by the reference types, not classes. From [JLS 4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3),

> There are four kinds of reference types: class types (§8.1), interface
>   types (§9.1), type variables (§4.4), and array types (§10.1).

Comment: Yeah Thanks for a more meaningful and short answer..One thing is still confusing that if array does not belong to any class then how its object is created as to create objects we need class..and also what is int[] ? is it is a class or something else?

Comment: @HasnainAbidKhanzada Arrays are completely different than classes. By the definition of object, you can see that a class is not mandated for object. Object can either be class instance or an array. `int[]` is a reference type not a class. Edited my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The array creation syntax for objects isn't really different than for primitives, e.g.

```
Box[] boxArray = new Box[5];
```

Now if you want to create boxes inside the array you would use the constructor syntax as:

```
boxArray[0] = new Box();
```

Note that I went ahead and capitalized `box` to `Box`, since starting class names with a capital letter is basically the accepted standard.

Comment: I think OP's confusion is not between primitive arrays and object arrays, but between arrays-as-objects and non-array-objects: why not `new int[](5)` and `new Box[](5)`, for example. If so, then the answer is probably convenience: creating a new array is a very common operation, and it is not silly to make an exception for common idioms if it is helpful. Also, all arrays are constructed in the same way, simply by allocating appropriate space.

Comment: I believe, this explanation does not serve the question.

Comment: In both array and class object, heap memory is used. Check the basics on that.